# C++ Error: "member Engine::x is not a type name"

Tags: c++, types, parameters

I'm bulding a standard 4 func calculator, and I'm trying to pass two numbers off as parameters that the user has entered. Within my Engine.h class I have declared

```
float num1, num2;
```

And I have the function

```
float Add(num1, num2);
```

In these params, num1 and num2 both have the error stated in the title: "Error: member Engine::num1 is not a type name." I'm very confused as to why these are bringing errors, isn't this how parameters work?

Comment: Provide the types of the parameters in the function declaration: `float Add(float num1, float num2);`

Comment: Thank you. I've been at this long enough to feel like I don't need to consult tutorials anymore, but it hasn't gone well obviously.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error, because I'm a noob and I thought that you could call the constructor of a member in it's declaration, like you would in a function:

```
private:
    MySmartClass myClass(getMySetting());
```

Needless to say, you can't do this, to call the constructor of a member you need to do this:

```
public:
        MyContainingClass() : myClass(getMySetting()) {}
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply declare the member function as

```
float Add() const;
```

As the function will deal with data members num1 and num2 it needs no parameters. For example it could be defined as

```
float Engine::Add() const
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

As for the error then you forgot to write type specifiers of the parameters.

Instead of

```
float Add(num1, num2);
```

there shall be at least

```
float Add( float num1, float num2);
```

Comment: this assumes that Add is a member function, AND num1 and num2 are member variables of some class that has not been mentioned.