# Cannot instantiate class inside other class. Member Map::value is not a type name

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, member, typename

```
сlass Chunk
{
private:
    size_t value;
public:
    Chunk(size_t value)
    {
        this->value;
    }
};

class Snake
{
private:
    size_t value;
    std::vector<Chunk> snake_body;
public:
    Snake(size_t value) 
    {
        Chunk head_chunk(value);
        snake_body.push_back(head_chunk);
    }
};

class Map
{
private:
    size_t value;
                            // Not able to find "snake" definiton
    Snake snake(value);     // member Map::value is not a type name
    Snake snake { value; }  // Why it works?
}
```

I'm newbie in OOP, trying to learn it by creating a game console-snake. Here's a problem i met. Structure of the game should be that class Map holds one snake. But when i am trying to instantiate it, i get a problem. Spent so many time on SOF, but nothing have found yet. And why it works with {} Please help ;/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Error: "member Engine::x is not a type name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353829/c-error-member-enginex-is-not-a-type-name)

Comment: @DarioPetrillo nuh, i do not understand the answers, so its a bit weird question for me, maybe due to lack of experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snake snake(value) is not valid syntax for initialization, and Snake snake{ value } is valid syntax(but probably initializes to an unitialized value since value is not initialized). Some more comments in code below :

```
class Map
{
public:
    // this is best if you want the main program to initialize snake with a user provided value
    explicit Map(size_t value) :
        snake{ value }              // aggregate initialization https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization
    {
    }

private:
    size_t value;           // if you use Snake{value} then also initialize value here, size_t value{0}; (or size_t value = 0;)
    // Not able to find "snake" definiton
    Snake snake(value);    //  <== this tries to make a call to the constuctor of Snake which can't be done here
    Snake snake{ value; }  // <== this is a valid initialization syntax, but uses unitialized value (so result can be any number)
}
```

Comment: Worth to mention that in constructor's initialiser list parentheses are valid syntax: `Map(...) : snake(value) {}` – especially in template programming this syntax is preferrable, as the uniform initialisation syntax might chose the wrong constructor if there's one with initialiser list and another one with compatible arguments!

Comment: @Aconcagua True, it is always worth double checking when to use {} and when to use (). Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @PepijnKramer Why in the line 'Snake snake(value)' constructor cannot be done there? And is it okay to use Snake snake{ value; } if there will be another class called Game, that will pass value to a Map constructor, and then this value will be passed to snake?

Comment: I didn't make the rules, that's what they are : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization. way 2). And yes if you have multiple Map instances then passing value in Map's constructor and passing it on to snake constructor is the way to go